# Python API for Kafka Consumer Group describe group to pull lag

Tags: python, apache-kafka

Is there any Python version of Kafka Describe Group to get the consumer lag from kafka?
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html#describe-group

Answer (score 0):

There is not, but that doesn't mean you couldn't use something like

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["kafka-consumer-groups", "--describe", ...])
```

Generally, you would use some external Kafka lag collector, such as Burrow for monitoring things without needing to write custom CLI parsing code